# Is there a way to find out if blocking is implemented by the website itself or my ISP?

Tags: website, ip-address, isp, blocking, internet-filter

Basically Im in a country where the government is known to block many sites/protocols..

And Im also aware that websites / servers can simply region block my IPaddress, and this has become more popular today than in the past..

I need a way to find out who is the perpetrator..

Answer (score 3):

You can use traceroute (tracert in windows) to partially determine where the blockage to a site is.  This tool works by setting the TTL (time to live) in the packet to 1...n and sending it to get the return indicating where it stopped.  This gives you a rough guess of the ip of the router at each distance away from you.  Irregularities in how the packet is routed might cause you to get different answers at the same distance, so it tries 3 times by default.

If it is blocked, you will get no return (*), and then you can try to determine where the previous hop was and guess who is blocking.

traceroute uses udp and ICMP packets, which might be blocked.  For a more accurate response, use tcptraceroute on the port you are trying to probe (for example, 80 for web).  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a current working free version of tcptraceroute for windows.

Comment: This is very nice information.. however this part, "you can try to determine where the previous hop was and guess who is blocking." -- This is my first time attempting such a thing, and I have no idea how to determine where the previous hop was. You dont have to go into too much detail if you dont feel like it, you may give me the key idea and terms which  I need to learn..

Comment: It lists the hops....so the previous hop would be the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

You can trace the route and see where the packets stop.

In command prompt enter: tracert "websites IP address"
then hit return, and you can watch the packet travel.

Comment: "you can watch the packet travel." I definatly dont know what you mean by that, how can I analyze the data returned to find out the location of the stopped packets?    .. sorry nobody taught me.... :(

Comment: @hosa No worries, essentially you can take the last IP address you receive from the trace route command. Then google who owns the IP address. Whoever owns it is the company that refused to let your packet travel to the next destination.